# Switched Capacitor with MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I have been trying to create a simple switched capacitor for my circuit, yet I must be doing something wrong and can't understand why it won't work.
[image]

When the MOSFET is ON, VGS=3.2V, whereas when it is OFF, VGS=0V. I want this 1pF capacitor to be addes to my circuit, which operates in the range of 4-6GHz. Normally, when the MOSFET is OFF, the capacitor should "see" an open circuit and not contribute its capacity to the circuit. However, no matter if the MOSFET is ON or OFF, I get the same result:
[image]

Can somebody please tell me what's going on here?
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MOSFET you have chosen (1RF530) is not at all suitable for a high frequency circuit.

It has an output capacitance of several hundred picofarad even when it is off. It is not going to make much difference changing the bias.

You need to find a device whose output capacitance is low relative to 1pF - I don't think you will find one. You may be able to use a diode switch to do what you want.

There are devices available that have electrically switchable capacitors or maybe a reed relay.

[1RF530 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/91019.pdf)

[Digital Programmable Capacitor](http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/NCD2100.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Start with [something simpler](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%202.5e-10%2030.13683688681966%2050%205%2050%0Af%20304%20240%20352%20240%2032%201.5%205%0Aw%20352%20256%20352%20304%200%0A172%20352%20144%20352%20112%200%207%205%205%200%200%200.5%20Drain%20Voltage%0Ag%20352%20304%20352%20320%200%0AR%20256%20240%20224%20240%200%202%201000000%205%205%200%200.5%0Al%20352%20144%20352%20224%200%200.000001%200.009680517750945044%0Ar%20304%20240%20256%20240%200%2010%0Ac%20416%20304%20416%20224%200%201e-9%20-126.08528381945221%0Ar%20512%20224%20512%20304%200%205000%0Aw%20368%20224%20352%20224%200%0Ap%20304%20240%20304%20304%201%204%0Aw%20304%20304%20352%20304%200%0Ad%20368%20224%20416%20224%202%20default%0Ap%20416%20224%20416%20208%201%204%0Aw%20416%20224%20512%20224%200%0Aw%20416%20304%20512%20304%200%0Ap%20512%20224%20512%20208%201%201%0A403%20448%20128%20576%20192%200%208_256_0_4354_160_0.1_0_2_8_3%0A403%20208%20128%20336%20192%200%200_128_0_4362_160_12.8_0_2_0_3%0Aw%20416%20304%20352%20304%200%0A) and don't try to go beyond 50MHz until you learn the geometry of stray capacitance and inductance.

There are too many mistakes in your schematic.

[image]